# How to pass server name to SQL Server Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scheduled-tasks, sql-agent-job

There is a SQL Server job going to create on server 1 .This is to run a T-SQL procedure with 2 parameters (`datefrom` and `dateto`), which is on server 2.

How to pass the server2 name in a SQL Server Agent job!?

I was trying to create a job steps like below

```
DECLARE @RC int

DECLARE @Load_From_Date varchar(20)
DECLARE @Load_To_Date varchar(20)

@Load_From_Date ='1/1/2016'
@Load_To_Date ='1/12/2016'

EXECUTE @RC = [server2].[db name].[dbo].[SpOnserver2] 
   @Load_From_Date
  ,@Load_To_Date
GO
```

This is not working

How to pass the server name to the SQL Server Agent job?

Is this the correct way to pass the date from and date to parameters?

There are 5 steps and all those 5 steps accepts these same parameters datefrom and dateto

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a stored procedure, In the title you are talking about a job, to run the job on a different server do something like this: EXEC [server2].msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'JobName'.

Comment: Do you have remote procedure calls enabled on your linked server connection between server1 and server2?

Comment: EXEC [server2].msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'JobName'...In this where to give the parameters?